# System of quadratic equations that is symmetric

Tags: polynomials

Solve for $z$: $z^2-3z+1=x, x^2-3x+1=z$

I see that it is symmetric, but not anything else.  Hints would be great, but please do not spoil the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

$$z^2-3z+1=x, x^2-3x+1=z \implies$$

$$(z-1)^2=x+z,(x-1)^2=z+x \implies$$

$$(z-1)^2=(x-1)^2$$

Comment: Very neat manipulation!

Comment: How do you solve for z after this?